# Can't set up React/Babel/Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

So I was trying to set up the React/Babel/Webpack environment but I had some trouble doing so. I started creating a new folder, did the `npm init` and then I followed everything in this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html

- First, I've installed webpack globally
- I've created a `index.js` with the same content on the tutorial
- I've created a `.babelrc` file with `{ "presets": ["react"] }`
- Ran the `npm install --save react react-dom babel-preset-react babel-loader babel-core`

Then, when I run the command `webpack main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'` it gives me an error: "Module parse failed ~ You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Any idea guys? I've literally copy and pasted every step from the tutorial and I am sure all the files are correct. Thanks in advice!

Comment: This should work, make sure everything is installed?

Comment: The problem seems to be the JSX code, the command works when I cut it off. But it looks like everything is fine. How could I make sure everything is installed?

Comment: There is `node_modules` folder, check there if everything has installed. 

Try:
`webpack main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel'`

Comment: When I use your command it says "Cannot resolve module webkpack in ~path".

Comment: Well the folder is pretty full of babel folders, has react and react dom as well....there's also many folders there that aren't from babel either, I'm guessing they came with react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file `webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path'); 
var webpack = require('webpack'); 

module.exports = { 
  entry: './main.js', 
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' }, 
  module: { 
    loaders: [{ 
      test: /.js?$/, 
      loader: 'babel-loader', 
      exclude: /node_modules/ 
    }] 
  }, 
};
```

Run

```
webpack
```

and it will generate `bundle.js` for you.

Now make sure you have added `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>Hello React!</title> 
  </head> 
<body> 
  <div id="example"></div> 
  <script src="bundle.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you accessing webpack from global. You might have installed webpack by doing

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Now, 
Install webpack locally,

```
npm install webpack
```

and run.

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'
```

Comment: Done it but is It says the dot isn't recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: And you are on windows or linux ? Okay. then last do `npm -g webpack` and run `webpack main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'`

Comment: I'm on windows. `npm -g webpack` isn't a command, did you mean `npm install -g webpack`? Still getting the module parser error

Comment: I meant `npm -g webpack` only. if dot is not working try doing, `node_modules/.bin/webpack main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'` or `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'`

Comment: When I do this, it gives me a message like npm is telling me how it works.

Comment: if dot is not working try doing, `node_modules/.bin/webpack main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'` or `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js main.js bundle.js --module-bind 'js=babel-loader'`

Comment: It says 'node_modules' is not recognized as an interna or external command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110691/discussion-between-vaibhav-mule-and-gbarroso).